# Translating spreadsheet into different language

Tags: google-translate, translate

I need to bulk translate an excel spreadsheet into a different a language

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Dump excel spreadsheet values into google spreadsheet

Run formula found here: `googletranslate(A1, "en", "es")` for english to spanish

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411

Use this for supported language shortnames

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages

Copy values paste back into excel